# SELECT from multiple tables same data and ignore other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

Im trying to select rows from multiple table who share some common data

Common data from table1 and table2 are: `name`, `content` BUT `table2` has `uname` instead of `name` but they are same

`table2` has an extra columns for `date` and `U` which i want to ignore but search by `U`
`table1` has extra column called `country` which i m ignoring

Actually im running 2 queries instead of 1

My two queries I'm running are:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, content FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE '%foo%'
SELECT DISTINCT uname, content, u FROM table2 WHERE uname LIKE '%foo%' AND U = 1
```

I have tried something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE t1.name LIKE '%foo%' AND t2.uname LIKE '%foo%' AND t2.U = 1
```

But it doesn't work as I want and I doubt if its good when talking performancewise .

I would appreciate your help

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe you want a `JOIN` with filtering:

```
select . . .  -- whatever columns you want here
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.name = t2.uname
where t1.name LIKE '%foo%' and t2.u = 1;
```

Comment: Is it possible to join to on multiple columns? for example if content from t2 was ucontent?

Comment: `on t1.name = t2.uname` become `on (t1.name = t2.uname) AND (t1.content = t2.ucontent)` right?

Comment: @niqqacoder . . . Yes, if that is the `JOIN` condition that you want.